# 404: NOT_FOUND on server site deploy

Tags: error-handling, deployment, server, http-status-code-404, vercel

Whenever I just **deploy** my server side in **vercel** after running the link it shows 404 error.So what should i do now?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd5sq.png)

I have tried with vercel --prod command and again I face the same ERROR when i run the link in browser

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See the details of the project and errors on vercel.com/dashboard with authenticated user

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found the solution. After reading some documents on google I found that there is a build command missing in package.json. Then I added the Build command And it's gonna working now.